# Error not logged - Java / WildFly

Tags: java, wildfly

I have a piece of legacy code which reads a file into a `StringBuilder` and sends it through some API. This code is running in WildFly with JRE 8 (pretty new/up-to-date environment).

I should note that a file is large - say around 280 MBs.
Now this code does not throw an exception, no exception or error is logged into the app or server logs. But the execution flow simply jumps out of this block, and goes into a finally block (in a calling method).

How can I see what exactly is happening? Seems I have an `Error` (not an `Exception`) here but I am not sure why WildFly is not logging it. If it's an `OutOfMemoryError`, it would be strange... since the app should have more than enough memory to read a file of 280 MBs (I think).

`java -D[Standalone] -server -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

Here is the code block that's giving me troubles.

```
    StringBuilder sbDataMessage = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fConvertedName), "UTF-8"));
    cnt = -1;
    while ((cnt = in.read(cBuffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) >= 0) {
        sbDataMessage.append(cBuffer, 0, cnt);
    }
    in.close();
    sendDataMessage(Integer.toString(currentBatch.getBatchId()), sbDataMessage.toString());
    sbDataMessage.delete(0, sbDataMessage.length());
    sbDataMessage = null;
```

Any ideas what's happening here, or how to troubleshoot it in some more details?

Comment: Could it be that this works correctly but sendDataMessage fails to send the data (over network?) due some restrictions? What is the expected result?

Comment: Not a great implementation since it a) needs to grow `StringBuilder`'s internal char buffer constantly which means there will be multiple increasingly (probably doubled each time) versions in memory (there is a constructor that pre-sizes it). Next, `StringBuilder#toString` needs to duplicate that buffer again so the `String` has it's own copy. At least 2x280MB needed at that point in time. If anything in `sendDataMessage` copies that data again you're easily using way more than you think.

Comment: @zapl Thanks, I am suspecting so. I will look into that. Thanks for the ideas.